# ExpressJS CORS error when req body json is too heavy

Tags: node.js, express, filesize

I have an expressJS server receiving API requests from a React APP front-end.

Anytime I push a request with an image less than 200Kb; it goes through as expected. But when the image parameter is exceeding 200Kb I get a CORS error.

[CORS error if file exceed 200Kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USoKw.png)

My setup for CORS and bodyParser size params:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(cors());
```

I'm stuck on this. Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Comment: Please provide and example of your error.

Comment: Just added the console error stack from my Browser. Despite that, the express JS does not give any error in the logs

Comment: I know it seems silly, have you tried having `app.use(cors());` first? Well I guess it is before your routes.

Comment: No Same... But I just got it right. I change from bodyParse.json to express.json with same Parameters and it works. I just don't get why ?!

Answer (score 3):

I just change from

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
```

to

```
app.use(express.json({limit: "50mb"}));
```

I'm not sure what's the big difference here; but that solved my issue.
Still it's really annoying that the size limit results into CORS error. Not really friendly to debug :/